# Perform remote cryptographic operations

Tags: .net, windows, cryptography, domaincontroller

I have 2 windows hosts in a same domain controller. One runs a webservice, and the other one has a certificate and access to its private key. I would like to be able to leverage the domain controller (or anything that makes it simple truthfully) to be able to consume the key pairs from my webservice to perform standard cryptographic operations (signing...). Is there a way to do that?

I looked into things such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certadm/nn-certadm-icertadmin#methods but I didn't find anything versatile enough to let me perform cryptographic operations like signing

Comment: To be honest, it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, and why you are pointing to management functions to perform signing. That could be me missing context when it comes to handling domain controllers, but some more information would be welcome by most I think.